# How to handle big integers (64 bit) numbers in tcl?

Tags: floating-point, tcl

what is the best way to handle big integers in expr command. we know wide in expr.

Comment: Can you be a bit more precise?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As of Tcl 8.5, integers are now Bignums (arbitrary precision)

If you're using an older version (which you've said you are, 8.4.x), you'll need to consider what you need to use the numbers for. Most of the standard commands won't accept Bignums, since it hadn't been added to the core at that time. However, if you're just doing math with them, you might want to take a look at

- the [tcllib package](http://wiki.tcl.tk/1246), which has a library for arbitrary precision math, or
- the [mexpr package](http://mpexpr.sourceforge.net/).

Lastly, it's worth [searching the Tclers Wiki](http://wiki.tcl.tk/_/gsearch?S=arbitrary+precision+integers&_charset_=UTF-8) for other options.

Comment: Is there something missing in this answer? Some other information you need? Never heard anything else from you, nor is it selected as the answer, so was hoping you might provide feedback.

Comment: Sorry... I am working on tcl library for geometrical problems, e.g. finding intersection of geometrical objects. I many cases I need to handle domain errors thrown by expr command. I am thinking to shift on c++. before I just wanted to confirm what I am doing...